# Algorithm to find all paths in a graph

Tags: python, graph-theory

Question

[image]

The above image is my problem statement for a practice assignment.

```
For the above problem, this was the idea I came up w/ for my recursive algorithm
Base case = you've hit a node u with no outgoing edges. `return [u]`
If there are outgoing edges from current node u to vertices v;
```

```
src_paths = []
for each v
    child_paths = recursivealgorithm(v)
    for each child_path in child_paths:
        src_path = [u] + child_path
        src_paths.append(src_path)
return src_paths
```

```
The trouble w/ this idea as defined is that there is no way to stop an infinite loop happening in case of a cycle in the graph. I thought of various ideas to prevent such a loop (such as keeping track of the vertices visited thus far, maintaining a dictionary including the distance of each visited vertex from the original src & somehow using that to tell if there was a cycle, etc.) but they all had the trouble of also causing issues if 2 child_paths ever converged at a vertex (without creating a cycle)

For eg
```

[image]

The above picture has no cycle, BUT if I write something like

```
if not visited[v]
```

as a condition to the main for loop displayed above, to prevent recursive calls to vertices that have been already visited, then (depending on the order in which python handles the recursive calls) either vertex 2 or vertex 4 is not going to be able to make a call to vertex 5 as 5 will already have been visited by 1 or the other of these.

How do I prevent cycles while allowing calls to vertices so long as said vertices have not occurred previously in the specific path leading to the current vertex?

Comment: Please don't hide textual information in an image. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're allowed to use [networkx](/questions/tagged/networkx) but if so, you can use [`all_simple_paths`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html) (*IIUC*) :

> `all_simple_paths`(G, source, target, cutoff=None)
> **Generate all simple paths in the graph G from source to target.**

```
#pip install networkx
import networkx as nx

def findAllPaths(vertices, gList, source, destination):
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    G.add_nodes_from(vertices)
    for u in gList:
        for v in gList[u]:
            G.add_edge(u, v)
    
    return list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=source, target=destination))
```

Test/Output (*based on the [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wotP.jpg)*) :

```
all_pp = findAllPaths(
             vertices=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             gList={1: [2, 3], 2: [5], 3: [4], 4: [5], 5: []},
             source=1,
             destination=5)

print(all_pp)
#[[1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

To find all paths between two vertices in a graph:

- Set cost of every edge to 1.
- Apply Dijkstra algorithm to find cheapest path between vertices
- Increment cost of links in path
- Repeat previous two steps until no new path is found